# mapnik configure fails during rpmbuild, but succeeds manually

Tags: awk, rpm, scons, rpmbuild, mapnik

I've posted this issue on the google groups area for mapnik already, so I'm just going to c/p from there:

I've been troubleshooting this issue for a couple days, now. Bear with me for context:

Starting from a freshly-untarred source of mapnik 2.2.0 on RHEL 6.5:

First off, running "./configure" (which just calls scons/scons.py) works great. Finishes correctly, then I run make + make install and I get exactly what I want built and installed.

My goal has been to create a mapnik 2.2.0 RPM for internal use. Please do not suggest using an "official" mapnik RPM instead (or any other already-built mapnik RPM), as my entire purpose here is to build mapnik from source and create my own RPM.

That being said, when my RPM gets to its %build phase and runs ./configure, it freezes while scons checks for freetype-config. I've let it sit for hours, and nothing happens.

After I looked at the generated config.log file, it would appear that configure is failing on an "awk" command that goes something like this:

```
awk '{print $\(NF-1\)}'
```

The command is performed on the string that results from the command:

```
/usr/bin/freetype-config --libs --cflags
```

I'm wondering, first of all, how to fix this, but second of all why this would work manually, but fail when the rpmbuild process gets to the ./configure command. I've made sure that the same user (myself) is running both ./configure commands on the exact same files.

My third question would be: why does the configure step freeze on this issue, instead of throwing some sort of error and stopping?

Note that the problem with the "awk" command is the backslashes--the error is:

```
awk: {print $\(NF-1\)} 
             ^ backslash not last character on line
```

When I remove the backslashes, the command succeeds. Whether or not removing the backslashes is the correct thing to do in the long run, I do not know.

It would seem this is some sort of python string-parsing / encoding issue, but I'm unsure. What really confuses me is why this works manually and fails when the rpmbuild tries to do it.

My only thought is that there's some difference between the rpmbuild environment and my shell that I configured on. What it is, I do not know.

Thank you for any assistance you can provide. If I can provide any more context, please let me know.

UPDATE: an svn command runs after the awk failure, but is missing whatever number gets passed after the `-r` option. I'm wondering if this could be causing the hang...thoughts?

Comment: If svn is called after the awk then awk is not hanging and yes that could certainly be what is hanging. You should be able to find out what is hanging by looking at the output from `ps faxww` when it is hung and seeing what the entry in that process tree is at that point. Do you have a custom PATH setup? Multiple versions of `awk` installed?

Comment: thank you for that--it looks like it's hanging on the following command: `grep \s*/etc/init.d/.*\s`. I ran the command myself and it hangs. Thoughts? I'm going to search through the source to see if I can find the command.

Comment: That needs input. It should be getting fed data from some other command via a pipeline I assume but that is failing (so grep waits until it gets some which seems to not be happening). Either the input failed entirely (i.e. the command was `grep ... $somefile` and `$somefile` was empty so it ended up as `grep ....` which is now hanging on standard input) or the command that is supposed to generate input has failed to do so and grep is just waiting.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'm looking more closely at the `ps -faxww` command, and it looks like my environment (`env`) is being used by scons, somewhere in one of its python scripts. There's a bunch of stuff in there from my rpmbuild process (function definitions, variables, etc.), and I'm wondering if any of that stuff could be throwing it off. As I mentioned in the original post, calling `./configure` manually works just fine, so it could very well be that something from my rpmbuild environment is screwing things up. Ideas on how to start with a "clean" env, without getting rid of essentials?

Comment: Not without tweaking the commands in the build or running scons cleanly (i.e. `env ./configure`). But if you are using an existing SRPM for mapnik to build your rpm then this should be known to work. Are you doing that or did you write your own?

Comment: I'm building my own RPM (writing my own .spec file).

Comment: Why? Or more specifically why aren't you using an exist SRPM and just building it yourself (after whatever modifications you want to make)? You should check what the official package's spec files look like. They may have patches/workarounds for dealing with things like this.

Comment: I will look at existing .spec files to see what they do, but the main reason I'm creating my own .spec file is to install mapnik to a different location and to use homebrewed boost, icu4c, etc., libraries and headers that I created RPMs for.

Comment: If your other RPM packages provide the same libraries/etc. that the official packages require then you don't need to rebuild mapnik at all for that (I'm assuming they don't or that they differ in version/etc.). You don't need to write your own spec file to change the location. Just edit the official one and use it. Don't rewrite this from scratch. Use what experienced packagers have put together and tweak it. You will save yourself much time and effort (and get any crucial patches/etc. as a bonus).

Comment: I performed the configure command prefixed with "env - PATH=$PATH HOME=${HOME}...etc" to preserve some key environment variables, and that seemed to do the trick. There are a lot of other reasons that factor into why we chose to create our own RPM, but I did take a look at an "official" .spec file for mapnik, and it's essentially the same as mine. The only difference was in the environments, which I believe I fixed. Thanks, though!

Comment: Just to be clear. "Building your own RPM" is not the same as "writing a spec file from scratch by hand". You should stop thinking of those as the same thing. In general you will save yourself much headache and hassle if you use (and modify) the upstream SRPM package/sources and spec file. But I'm glad that worked. Though I wonder what you could have been setting that could have confused things. (This is part of why CentOS/etc suggest using `mock` for builds too by the way.)